# Cannot insert row into table after creating a trigger

Tags: mysql

I get an error when inserting a row into a table after creating this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER aio_mtltp2016 AFTER INSERT ON master_table_linfomastp2016
BEGIN
        IF master_table_linfomastp2016 (IMHQ_solicitado = 'SI')
        THEN 
        INSERT INTO imhq (ID_CASO,Tipo_de_estudio,Año,Codigo_interno,Iniciales_Px,Sexo,Edad)
        VALUES (NEW.ID_CASO, NEW.Tipo_de_estudio, NEW.Año, NEW.Codigo_Interno, NEW.Iniciales_Px, NEW.Sexo, NEW.Edad);
        END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The record im inserting is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `master_table_linfomastp2016` (`ID_CASO`, `Tipo_de_estudio`, `Año`, `Codigo_interno`, `Iniciales_Px`, `Sexo`, `Edad`, `Servicio_solicitante`, `Roche_Hospital`, `Especimen`, `Macro`, `Diagnóstico`, `subtipo_ltp`, `FISH_solicitado`, `IMHQ_solicitado`, `laminilla_encontrada`, `laminilla_revisada`, `bloque_recibido`, `punch_realizado`, `en_microarreglo`, `validado_por`, `n_marcadores_solicitados`, `Localizacion`, `registro_HU`) VALUES (NULL, 'P', '15', '9106', 'IAS', 'M', '34', 'Hospital Universitario', NULL, 'BIOPSIA', 'REVISION DE LAMINIALLAS', 'LINFOMA NO HODGKIN T PERFIERICO NO ESPECIFICADO', 'Celulas T perifericas (Sin otra especificacion)', 'NO', 'SI', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'JPF', '12', 'NODAL', '1383250-3')
```

and it says:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION linfomas_t_bd.master_table_linfomastp2016 does not exist
```

where did i go wrong? the insertion of records works if i remove the trigger, but I cannot insert records after creating the trigger and it gives me that error.

If i change the syntax from ` to ' it gives me syntax error. It also says sometimes that the table does not exist. What am i doing wrong? Im using phpMyAdmin but the trigger I made was using direct mysql input, not the trigger creator. The trigger is created without problems.

Comment: Shouldn't you just check the New.IMHQ_solicitado = 'SI' in the IF statement? The trigger is for the table master_table_linfomastp2016, so there is no need to reference that in the IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF statement should only check the column that is being inserted for 'SI', see revised code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER aio_mtltp2016 AFTER INSERT ON master_table_linfomastp2016
BEGIN
        IF New.IMHQ_solicitado = 'SI'
        THEN 
        INSERT INTO imhq (ID_CASO,Tipo_de_estudio,Año,Codigo_interno,Iniciales_Px,Sexo,Edad)
        VALUES (NEW.ID_CASO, NEW.Tipo_de_estudio, NEW.Año, NEW.Codigo_Interno, NEW.Iniciales_Px, NEW.Sexo, NEW.Edad);
        END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```